# How to get Azure easy auth JWT access_token

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have an Azure App Service on which I have enabled Authentication/Authorization and configured AD as the authentication provider.

All `/.auth` routes exist on the service, and I can log in. After successful login I can call `/.auth/me` to get the `access_token`. The response looks like:

```
[
  {
     "access_token": "AQABAAAAAA...Gni4EiQgAA",
     "expires_on": "2017-02-28T19:17:08.0000000Z",
     "id_token": JWT TOKEN
     ...
  }
]
```

I then use the `access_token` in an authorization bearer header to request data from the service.

```
"Authorization": "Bearer " + "AQABAAAAAA...Gni4EiQgAA"
```

My service returns the following error

```
IDX10708: 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.JwtSecurityTokenHandler' cannot read this string: 'AQABAAAAAA...Gni4EiQgAA'.

The string needs to be in compact JSON format, which is of the form: '<Base64UrlEncodedHeader>.<Base64UrlEndcodedPayload>.<OPTIONAL, Base64UrlEncodedSignature>'.
```

According to [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38419058/how-to-refresh-an-id-token-from-azure-ad-in-a-web-app) the `access_token` is intended to be used as a Bearer token. I have also read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-token-and-claims#access-tokens) that the `access_token` is supposed to be base64 encoded but this does not appear to be the case.

Additionally, if I use the `id_token` as a Bearer token, then authentication works as expected (the `id_token` is in JWT format).

**Edit**

When I manually implement the Oauth flow as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code#use-the-authorization-code-to-request-an-access-token), I receive a proper JWT `access_token`.

```
GET
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?client_id=client_id&response_type=code&redirect_uri=redirect_uri
```

Followed by

```
POST
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token
  grant_type=authorization_code
  client_id=client_id
  code=CODE FROM ABOVE
  redirect_uri=redirect_uri
  resource=resource
  client_secret=client_secret

RESPONSE
{
  "access_token": JWT TOKEN,
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  ...
}
```

Comment: What is your setting on your back end server?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How to get Azure easy auth JWT access_token

According to your description, I enabled Authentication/Authorization and configured AD as the authentication provider to test this issue. As I known, when you enable Authentication/Authorization on Azure Portal, then the default `response_type` is `id_token`. You need to log into https://manage.windowsazure.com and update App Service Auth Configuration as follows:

[image]

**Note:** If you do not specify the `resource` for `additionalLoginParams`, you would retrieve a access_token that is not in JSON Web Token (JWT) format.

> I then use the access_token in an authorization bearer header to request data from the service.

For accessing your service, you could leverage `AppServiceAuthSession` cookie or you could use `Authorization:Bearer "{your-id-token}"`.

For more details, you could refer to this similar [tutorial](http://cgillum.tech/2016/03/25/app-service-auth-aad-graph-api/).

Comment: Thanks! This pointed me in the right direction. However I wonder why this setting is obscured away when the whole permission assignment flow has a UI.

Comment: @Nitin I know I'm replying to this after 3 years. But my objective is the same. And doing so results in a 500 Internal Error response after login. The NodeJS app works perfectly without any additional login param. But adding `resource=https://graph.microsoft.com` results in 500

Comment: The resource here should be the identifier for the thing you are trying to grant access to. In my case it was a Function App which we've built separately. So I provided its Application ID GUID identifier from Azure AD. Alternatively this could have been its URL as configured in the Azure AD.

Comment: But like Bruce has said, I should be able to get access to graph. Or is it that there is some other ID I have to use? But when I did this the `myapp.com/.auth/me` end point works and gives me a JWT which works with graph. But the app at `myapp.com ` returns 500

Comment: I think you need to go here to do this now: [Resource Explorer](https://resources.azure.com/) per [Refresh identity provider tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-authentication-how-to#refresh-identity-provider-tokens)