# Azure client app accessing Azure api secured by AD

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have an Angular 5 app and a web api app, both of which are hosted in Azure.

They have been secured with Azure AD at the website level e.g. no anonymous access is allowed.

When browsing the Angular site, it asks me to log in fine and I can access `.auth/me` which uses the local cookie to get token/claim information.

I now want to call the separate api but not sure how to go about it.

Both sites have an application in Azure AD, and I've set the client to have delegated permissions of 'Access to API'.

I've tried accessing the api using both the local cookie from the client (not sure if this would work) and the token returned `.auth/me` but neither work.

In my client manifest I have the following:

```
"resourceAppId": "3cddd33c-2624-4216-b686-7f8fa48f38cf", // api id
  "resourceAccess": [
    {
      "id": "c2712c68-ea93-46d2-9874-61b807b19241",
      "type": "Scope"
    }
  ]
```

but haven't seen any additional scopes added to the claims, should it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your description, you have both created the separate AAD application for your Angular app and your web api app, and configured the delegated permissions for your Angular AAD app to access the web api AAD app.

Based on my understanding, you are using the build-in [App Service Authentication / Authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-authentication-overview) for authentication, at this point you could do not need to change code on your app backend. You may have set **Action to take when request is not authenticated** to **Log in with Azure Active Directory** instead of allowing anonymous access, at this time your app service would directly redirect the user for authentication. After logged, your client could access `https://{your-angular-app-name}.azurewebsites.net/.auth/me` for retrieving the logged user info. For accessing your web api website, you could just send the request as follows in your angular client:

```
GET https://{your-webapi-app-name}.azurewebsites.net/api/values
Header Authorization:Bearer {id_token or access_token of AAD}
```

**UPDATE:**

> That is exactly the route I'm trying to implement. One thing missing though, I had to add the client application id to the `allowed token audience` of the api app in Azure.

For retrieving the access_token, you need to set additional settings for the AAD provider in your Angular web app as follows:

```
"additionalLoginParams": [
  "response_type=code id_token",
  "resource=<AAD-app-id-for-your-webapi-webapp>"
]
```

Details you could follow this similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42517785/how-to-get-azure-easy-auth-jwt-access-token/42529542#42529542).

Use the EasyAuth server flow for logging, you would get the access_token, and you could leverage https://jwt.io/ to decode your token as follows:

[image]

Pass the access_token as the bearer token to your webapi web app, at this time you do not need to specific the **ALLOWED TOKEN AUDIENCES**.

At this time, you could invoke `.auth/refresh` against your Angular web app for refreshing the access_token, then you could use the new access_token to access your webapi web app.

> I want roles included in the token so might have to stick with id?

If you want your Web API exposing access scopes to your Angular application which would be contained in the access_token as the `scp` property, you could follow the **Configuring a resource application to expose web APIs** section in this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-integrating-applications). Moreover, you could also follow [Application roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/multitenant-identity/app-roles).

**UPDATE2:**

You could follow [Authorization in a web app using Azure AD application roles & role claims](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-roleclaims) for detailed tutorial and code sample.

Comment: That is exactly the route I'm trying to implement. One thing missing though, I had to add the client application id to the `allowed token audience` of the api app in Azure

Comment: So that's authenticating now with the id_token, but not with the access_token. And when I call `.auth/refresh` this only refreshes the access token, not the id_token so when the token expires I have to logout and log back in. How do I get the api to accept the access token and not id? Or how do I refresh the id_token? I want roles included in the token so might have to stick with id?

Comment: I updated my answer for explanation, you could refer to it.

Comment: Perfect, got EasyAuth working, thanks very much for that! I'm still a bit confused about the roles though. So a user has a specific role within the app/api (say admin or user). Would I define this as oauth2pemissions or roles? In the API? And then where do I assign the user to the role/scope? From the examples I've seen it's more giving the application a role, not specific users

Comment: You could just follow the github sample [Authorization in a web app using Azure AD application roles & role claims](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-roleclaims). Any concerns, feel free to let us know. If my answer could help you, kindly mark it as an acceptable answer.

Comment: That sample is a bit different as it's not a separate api from the client. Am I correct in thinking that defining scopes in an API are at the client application level (i.e. the app has the permissions) whereas if I want to do it at the user level (e.g. a user might have admin permissions on the api, whereas another user will have readonly) this will have to use roles? And then would this role have to be defined in both the client and api and user in both?

Answer (score 0):

The usual approach would be to use ADAL.JS (or MSAL.JS with AAD v2 endpoint/B2C) to get an access token for the API.

ADAL.JS uses a hidden iframe to get an access token using the user's active session in Azure AD.

You can find an example Angular app here: [GitHub](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-angularjs-singlepageapp-dotnet-webapi).

An especially important part of the ADAL.JS configuration is [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-angularjs-singlepageapp-dotnet-webapi/blob/master/TodoSPA/App/Scripts/app.js#L24):

```
var endpoints = {
    // Map the location of a request to an API to a the identifier of the associated resource
    "https://myapi.azurewebsites.net/": "https://myaadtenant.onmicrosoft.com/MyApi"
};
```

The property name/key should be the URL for your API. ADAL-Angular detects calls to URLs starting with that, and attaches the correct access token to them.

The value should be the App ID URI of the API. You can find it from your API's App Registration from Azure Active Directory -> App registrations -> All Apps -> Your API -> Settings -> Properties.

You do need to enable implicit grant flow on the Angular app from the app registration for the SPA. You can find it from the Manifest.

Comment: Thanks for that, I'll have a look at the sample. I was hoping that as I've secured the site at the site level, I wouldn't need to do any of the ADAL stuff. The client app is secured and I've already got a token using `.auth/me`, just not sure about using it to access the API.