# Azure Google authentification get user profile info

Tags: android, azure, authentication, oauth, google-api

I am using Azure mobile services to store data from my Android app. Users have to log in using Google and I've used Azure's Easy Auth to implement that.

However, I also need the display name and the email of the user. I have searched a lot and couldn't find a way how to get the info. I know that for other providers like Facebook or Microsoft you can just check attributes that should be included in the response (e.g. [Microsoft as provider](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaushal/2016/04/01/azure-web-apps-how-to-retrieve-user-email-in-the-claim-when-using-microsoft-account-as-a-provider-in-easy-auth/)) but with Google, Azure doesn't provide any attributes.

Answer (score 2):

I just followed [How to configure your App Service application to use Google login](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-google-authentication) to configure my App Service Authentication (Easy Auth) for Google login. I just leverage the [Server-managed authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-dotnet-how-to-use-client-library#serverflow) and log with my mobile app backend via the browser as follows:

```
GET https://<your-app-name>.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/google
```

Using fiddler to capture the network traces as follows:

[image]

Then, access the `/.auth/me` endpoint via the browser, I could retrieve the user email as follows:

[image]

Moreover, you could follow [Obtaining user profile information](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#obtaininguserprofileinformation). Also, you could access `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token=<access_token>` to retrieve the user profile manually.

Additionally, if you want to modify the google OAuth Scopes (set `googleOAuthScopes` array property via `https://resources.azure.com`) or retrieve the refresh token (access_type=offline), you could follow this similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42517785/how-to-get-azure-easy-auth-jwt-access-token/42529542#42529542). And you could follow [App Service Token Store](https://cgillum.tech/2016/03/07/app-service-token-store/) for more details about App Service Authentication.